# Clicking on status bar does not scroll to top of app (Trigger.io)

Tags: javascript, ios, scroll, statusbar, trigger.io

I am using trigger.io to deploy my app to IOS.

However I observe that the standard function of clicking the status bar on the iPhone to scroll the app to the top is not working.

Is there anything I can do to resolve this?

Answer (score 5):

At the moment, no - we do have a story in our backlog to fire events when the user taps the topbar, but no ETA yet.

Comment: Would this potentially work for trigger too?
https://github.com/j-mcnally/cordova-statusTap

Comment: Interesting! Yep, at first glance I don't see why the same approach couldn't be taken with a native module: https://trigger.io/docs/current/api/native_modules/index.html